# ajax multipart/form-data post charset utf-8

Tags: php, ajax, utf-8, multipartform-data

I have a form with a file upload and an text input that requires UTF-8 encoding. When I try to send the form via ajax, I can't change the `contentType` to `false`, so how can I protect my text as well!?

```
    $.ajax({
            url         : 'url';?>',
            type: "POST",             
            data: new FormData(this), 
            contentType: false,       
            cache: false,            
            processData:false,        
            success: function(data)   
            {      
                 alert 'ok';
            }
```

Comment: can you provide complete code of ajax request

Comment: @user3731557 , format your code properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code on form submit:

```
$("#formId").submit(function(){

    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'your_url',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: this code will set the content type to multipart/form-data by default, how can i encode the text to charset ut-8

Comment: you can use this: mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');

Comment: mysql already set to utf-8 so i need to set utf-8 before the request goes to php

Comment: than use this one to modify the http header: header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, I don't get the question at all, every ajax post is in utf-8. Check [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send)

> If the data is a Document, it is serialized before being sent. When
>   sending a Document, versions of Firefox prior to version 3 always
>   sends the request using UTF-8 encoding; Firefox 3 properly sends the
>   document using the encoding specified by body.xmlEncoding, or UTF-8 if
>   no encoding is specified.